# How to include @xml:lang attribute only if it exists?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am transforming TEI XML to XHTML. I need to transform `xml:lang` attribute to `lang` attribute only if it exists for the current node. I tried some a bit clumsy things like:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:p">
    <xsl:element name="p">
        <xsl:attribute name="lang">
            <xsl:value-of select="./@xml:lang"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

… but I would like to stick to the best practices. How to simply take the `xml:lang` attribute and transform it into `lang` attribute? Of course, if it is not present, don’t use it at all.

I have added the famous Identity rule to my template (here [according to Michael Kay](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html#d5916e13)) but it does nothing:

```
<!-- Identity Rule -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@xml:lang">
    <xsl:attribute name="lang">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute> 
</xsl:template>
```

I guess I don’t understand the rule properly.

I want to use that for any tag, like:

```
<p xml:lang="en">
    <seg xml:lang="fr">XYZ</seg> otherwise English.
</p>
```

Expected output:

```
<p lang="en">
    <seg lang="fr">XYZ</seg> otherwise English.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your identity template should also process child nodes, otherwise it would stop at the first matched node :

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@xml:lang">
    <xsl:attribute name="lang">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, actually, I consider this solution cleaner than the one from @TimC but this one does not work. Is there any specific place I have to put this in if I use imports? Or does it have lower priority?

Comment: Oh, I see it works **with** the answer from @TimC! It means these two answers are the solution.

Comment: Does the order `@*|node()` matter? Or would it be also possible `node()|@*`?

Comment: The order doesn't matter AFAICS... It should always return result in document order, which I guess, attributes come first

Answer (score 2):

If you have an existing template matching `tei:p` then this will take priority over the identity template. Your current template does `<xsl:apply-templates />` but this is equivalent of `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />`. It is not processing attributes.

What you need to do is replace the current `xsl:attributes` with `xsl:apply-templates` instead, but selecting the `@xml:lang` attribute, allowing the relevant template to match it.

```
<xsl:template match="tei:p">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./@xml:lang"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

So, if `@xml:lang` does not exist, nothing is selected, and no attribute is created.

Comment: As I wrote below the answer from @har07, his and yours answers somehow work together. I consider this as solved but really don’t know who is the winner.

Comment: Feel free to accept @har07's answer, that is fine. He spotted the crucial point that I had missed.